# Angular2 router-link issue when injecting a template component with router links

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

**Angular2 router-link issue when injecting a template component with router links**

I have an app.ts file and I want to dependency inject my navigation component into my app.ts file.

I've made a navigation component that has a template and no functionality.
The template injects fine into app.ts. However, when I add the route-links to the template I always get console errors when using router-links only.

**Here is my navigation component ts file:**

```
 import {Component, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';

 @Component({
   selector: 'HeaderNavigation'
 })

 @View({
   templateUrl: '/src/app/components/header/header.html'
 })

 export class HeaderNavigation{

 }
```

**Here is my navigation component html file:**

```
 <header>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li class="active"><a [router-link]="['./Login']">Log In</a></li>
         </ul>
     </nav>   

     <router-outlet></router-outlet>       
 </header>
```

**This is my app.ts file: This file injects the navigation component above:**

```
 import {Component, View, bootstrap, bind, provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
 import {Router, ROUTER_BINDINGS, RouterOutlet, RouteConfig, RouterLink, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';
 import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2';
 import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

 import {Login} from './components/login/login';
 import {HeaderNavigation} from './components/header/header';

 @Component({
     selector: 'app'
 })

 @View({
     template: `
         <HeaderNavigation></HeaderNavigation>

         <div class="content">
             <router-outlet></router-outlet>    
         </div>
     `,
     directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink]
 })

 @RouteConfig([
     { path: '/', redirectTo: '/login' },
     { path: '/login', component: Login, as: 'Login' }
 ])

 @Injectable()

 export class AppComponent {
     constructor(){}
 }

 bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}), HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

**This is the error message I get from my console:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own question!
 was missing from the navigation html component and then I had the router-link name wrong and changed it to "Login" from "login" to match it in router config in the app.ts file.

I have made these changes in the above code for anyone who needs it.

Answer (score 0):

For those using angular 2 rc4, here is what i'm using:
header.component.ts

```
import { Component }    from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }    from '@angular/router';
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'ui-header',
   templateUrl: 'header.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['header.component.css'],
   directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

export class HeaderComponent{
}
```

To add header in other component: other.component.ts

```
import { Component }            from '@angular/core';
import { Router }               from '@angular/router';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }    from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderComponent }      from'../shared/header/header.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'ui-other',
    template: `
    <ui-header></ui-header>
    <div class = "container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
   `,
   directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, HeaderComponent]
})

export class OtherComponent {
}
```